# Serving Jupyter Notebook from within docker container on AWS not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I've set up an Ubuntu 14.04 AWS instance. My security group has port 8888 open (tcp), and port 22 open for ssh.

I can ssh into the instance just fine, then in the instance I start a docker container:

```
docker run -it --name="test" -p 8888:9999 b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
```

This container has jupyter notebook in it, then in the container I run `jupyter notebook` and I see the correct output:

```
[I 14:49:43.788 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/
[I 14:49:43.788 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

And if I run `docker ps` by opening another ssh, connection I see:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                         COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
8414f19fcd5f        b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel   "/bin/bash"         38 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes       6006/tcp, 8888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8888->9999/tcp   test
```

So everything seems correct, but I do not see jupyter notebook at: http://PUBLICIP:8888

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
docker run -it --name="test" -p 8888:9999 b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
```

The trick was to use:

```
docker run -it --name="test" -p 8888:8888 b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
```

Edit, thanks to DDW for the explanation:

"-p 8888:9999 doesn't stand for a range, it means port 9999 of your docker container is mapped to port 8888. 8888 is probably your standard notebook port, so it is logical that 8888:8888 works."

If you want to have two ports open then the command would be:

```
docker run -it --name="test" -p 8888:8888 -p 9999:9999 b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
```

Comment: What do you mean the entire range? -p 8888:9999 doesn't stand for a range, it means port 9999 of your docker container is mapped to port 8888. 8888 is probably your standard notebook port, so it is logical that 8888:8888 works. If your security group would have had port 6666 open you could have used 6666:8888 and then Public_ip:6666 would have shown your notebook interface.

Comment: @DDW spot on, for some reason I thought x:y was range, since that is the syntax in python for range

Comment: Maybe somehow copy-paste my answer in yours so we can accept it. Many people are confused about the port mapping thing!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to add `--network="host"` to docker run command
However it comes with some other effects be aware.

You can checkout from

[https://docs.docker.com/network/host/#:~:text=If%20you%20use%20the%20host,its%20own%20IP%2Daddress%20allocated](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20use%20the%20host,its%20own%20IP%2Daddress%20allocated)

https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#enable-forwarding-from-docker-containers-to-the-outside-world

Because I think , it is a docker network problem.